# regex capture html hidden input

Tags: python, html, regex

im trying to capture joomla token whit python pycurl,
im write this function code :

```
import urllib, urllib2, sys, re
import cStringIO
import pycurl

def CaptureToken(cURL):
    buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, cURL)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
    c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
    c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 30)
    c.perform()
    html = buf.getvalue()
    buf.close()
    results = re.match(r"(type=\"hidden\" name=\"([0-9a-f]{32})\")", html).group(1)
    print results

CaptureToken('http://www.proregionisbono.org.pl/administrator/index.php')
```

IN notepad++ this regex working, in python not working :(, please somebody help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.match` matches from the beginning of the string, you probably want `re.search` which will match anywhere within the string.

[Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)

This version of your code works for me:

```
import urllib, urllib2, sys, re
import cStringIO
import pycurl

def CaptureToken(cURL):
    buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, cURL)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
    c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30) 
    c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 30) 
    c.perform()
    html = buf.getvalue()
    buf.close()
    results = re.search(r'(type="hidden" name="([0-9a-f]{32})")', html).group(2)
    print results

CaptureToken('http://www.proregionisbono.org.pl/administrator/index.php')
```

Comment: *AND* nice switch from enclosing the RE pattern in "s to enclosing in 's, so that `\"` is no longer required.